# Use of phrase "teach or disclose" in OA responses

Tags: rejection, oa

The question is in context of a response attempting to overcome the examiner's cited prior art in a rejection. If stating that the prior art in question doesn't exactly address the point being used for rejection, is there a distinction between saying

*"the xxxx art does not **teach**..."*

and

*"the xxxx art does not **teach or disclose**..."* ?

Answer (score 2):

the basic difference between the both lies between content of prior art

Eg. you have developed a product consisting of 
 1. aaa
 2. bbb
 3. ccc
 4. ddd

**Scenario 1:** In the above example the prior art has aaa, bbb, ccc but not ddd then

> the prior art XXXX doesn't teach or disclose the use of ddd

**Scenario 2**: In the above example the prior art has of aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd,But in the prior art the compound is used for a different purpose than that of your intention.( eg: in prior art the compound ddd is disclosed  as lubricant but in your invention you are using it as a solvent)

> the prior art XXXX doesn't teach the use of ddd as an solvent.